# How to convert windows saved csv to webserver on linux

Tags: java, jsf, csv

The problem is that I have a windows excel exported CSV with Swedish letters åäöÅÄÖ. When I upload them and convert to string I get those letters completely messed up. The server is tomcat7 on linux. It's set to use iso-8859-1.

I have tried different byte[] conversions but none seem to work. I have removed all conversions I have tried from this code.

```
public void run(InputStreamReader is) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ";";


        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(is);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    // use comma as separator
                String[] playerInfo = line.split(cvsSplitBy);


                System.out.println("Förnamn: " + playerInfo[0] 
                                    + "Efternamn: " + playerInfo[1]
                                    + "Klubb= " + playerInfo[7] 
                                     + " , datum=" + playerInfo[10] 
                                     + " , Total= " + playerInfo[14] 
                                     + " , serier= " + playerInfo[15]);

                saveInfo(playerInfo);

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
      }
```

Comment: You can specify an encoding when you use a `Reader`. Windows probably uses windows-1252 by default, so try that

Comment: As fge has said, make sure your StreamReader input parameter has been created with the proper encoding (please show us how did you create it?)

Comment: is = file.getInputstream();
isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "windows-1252");